# Unexpected logout after submit form Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

When I click on [this](https://i.imgur.com/1umYmTW.png) submit button, the user is redirected to login form, throwing [this exception](https://i.imgur.com/3P7qNk6.png). As you can see in the first link, the user coming from `Auth::user()` method is there. Both of this routes are inside `Route::middleware(['auth'])->group()` in `routes/web.php`.

But here is another problem: Sometimes it works! Submitting the form works fine not throwing that exception.

All other routes works fine, except this one.

The only thing I have changed from scaffold `auth` is making another guard for `admins`. 
I also tried to use `database session storage`, without success.

config/auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::middleware(['auth','verified'])->group(function() {
    ...
    Route::prefix('/booking')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/checkout',...);
        Route::post('/checkout/pay',...);
    });

});
```

What I did wrong? Did I miss something?

Laravel version: 6.14.0

Comment: Is this an issue when running the site locally? You're not running multiple server instances behind a load balancer or anything, are you?

Comment: It happens localhost and in the server. I'm running only one instance with php artisan serve.